# 405 when using AttributeRouting.PUTAttribute unless I also include HttpPutAttribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

We have an MVC project that I am attempting to update to include WebApi.  In order to get the required routes we are using AttributeRouting. All the calls seem to be routing correctly except for [PUT] which returns a 405.  I have simplified the controller and actions and still receive the error with the [PUT] unless I include [HttpPut] also. Not sure what I am missing.

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/Sites")]
    public class SitesController : BaseApiController
    {
        [POST("")]
        public bool CreateSite(SiteSignupArgs args)
        {
            ...
        }

        [GET("Statuses")]
        public IList<SiteAuditViewModel> GetStatuses()
        {
            ...
        }

        [PUT("Statuses/{siteId}")]
        [HttpPut] // This is required or 405 is returned 
        public HttpResponseMessage UpdateStatus(string siteId, UpdateStatusArgs args)
        {
            ...
        }

        [DELETE("Statuses/{siteId}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Delete(string siteId)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
}
```

Version 3.5.6 of AttributeRouting.Core, AttributeRouting.Core.Http, AttributeRouting.Core.Web, AttributeRouting.WebApi

MVC4

WebDAV is not installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are seeing is an expected behavior. Action Selector in Web API by default assumes the action to be of verb `POST` if the action name does not have a prefix with verbs like "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete" etc.

Now it isn't working even if you have specified `[PUT("Statuses/{siteId}")]` attribute explicitly because, Action selector looks for attributes from `System.Web.Http` namespace like HttpGetAttribute, HttpPostAttribute, HttpPutAttribute etc.

Since AttributeRouting's PUTAttribute isn't of the above types, Action selector doesn't consider it and still thinks it to be the default one, which is `POST`. So your workaround of having `HttpPut` attribute is correct.

Comment: @kiran I wish I found this far sooner, I spent so many hours trying to figure this out.  Thanks for confirming it.

For google:
asp.net 405 method not allowed