# MVC AttributeRouting With GET - Returning 405 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I've just been working on a new controller action method and I'm a little confused why I'm seeing a 405.

I have defined several GET attributed methods on my API already and they all function as expected.  For an example this works fine:

```
    [GET("entries/{page}"), JsonExceptionFilter]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetEntries(int page)
```

Yet my new method defined like this:

```
    [GET("search/{searchTerm}/{page}"), JsonExceptionFilter]
    public HttpResponseMessage Search(string searchTerm, int page)
```

Is returning a 405

If I visit the routes.axd url on the API I can see an entry in the table like this:

```
GET, HEAD, OPTIONS  users/search/{searchTerm}/{page}
```

This all looks correct.  On the client side I'm using the same approach on both requests using an HttpClient:

```
var response = httpClient.GetAsync(ApiRootUrl + "users/search/" + searchTerm + "/" + page).Result;
```

Running a get from Fiddler also returns a 405.

Even looking at the RequestMessage in the response looks correct:

```
"{Method: GET, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:51258/users/search/jam/0'"
```

Totally stumped on this.

What else can I try to maybe shed some light on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to decorate the Search action with one more attribute called `System.Web.Http.HttpGetAttribute`. For the reason behind this, you can take a look at my answer in the below post:

[405 when using AttributeRouting.PUTAttribute unless I also include HttpPutAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196731/405-when-using-attributerouting-putattribute-unless-i-also-include-httpputattrib/17197131#17197131)

Comment: Slaps forehead ... well done, I even knew that naming convention rule, couldn't see the wood for the trees.  Thanks.