# 405 method not allowed in ASP.Net Web API Controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I've looked around to try to find some posts on this and there are many rather a lot but none that address my specific question (that I could find).

In my Api Controller there are many other methods with "**GET**" which are working fine but when I added a new method it's returning **405 method not allowed** message

```
 [GET("GetNames/{Id}/{Age}")]
 public List<Names> Names(long Id, string Age)
  {
    ...
    ...
  }
```

but when I put `[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]` on my method it's start working.

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
 [GET("GetNames/{Id}/{Age}")]
 public List<Names> Names(long Id, string Age)
  {
    ...
    ...
  }
```

Can anyone please explain me what I am doing wrong or this is the correct way. I found almost same question [MVC AttributeRouting With..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235826/mvc-attributerouting-with-get-returning-405-method-not-allowed) and [405 when using..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196731/405-when-using-attributerouting-putattribute-unless-i-also-include-httpputattrib/17197131#17197131) but still confused.

Answer (score 0):

Web API by default assumes the action to be of verb POST if verbs like "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete" are not specified.

Also you have given [GET("GetNames/{Id}/{Age}")] attribute explicitly, and its a object of GETAttribute.
Action selector looks for attributes from System.Web.Http namespace like HttpGet,HttpGetAttribute, HttpPostAttribute, HttpPutAttribute etc.

```
So remove [GET("GetNames/{Id}/{Age}")].
do not remove [HttpGet]
Create a custom route in app_start/WebApiConfig.cs file for this action if needed.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you have

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

remove it and add

```
using System.Web.Http;
```